# Need help with Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder Proof at ProofWiki

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This concerns Proof 6 of the CBST theorem [at ProofWiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder_Theorem/Proof_6).

I am stuck on the line beginning "Similarly, let $g' = $"

The 2nd equality on this line is not immediately obvious to me. How do you prove $A-X = g(B -f(X))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few lines up from your quote, we see the statement:

> Thus by $(1)$: $g\left(B \setminus f(X)\right) = A \setminus X$

This is the only thing that is used. It is proved in the lines following the lemma.

Comment: Thanks, but how embarrassing! I don't deserve those up-votes.

Comment: Link to my formal proof of CBST: http://dcproof.com/CBS.htm

Answer (score 1):

From the second displayed line of the part of the proof after the lemma showing that $E$ is increasing, you know that

$$A\setminus g\big[B\setminus f[X]\big]=X\;,$$

which is equivalent to

$$A\setminus X=g\big[B\setminus f[X]\big]\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is my formal version of the proof of the [Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder Theorem](http://www.dcproof.com/CBS.htm). Thanks all for your help.